# Function when call poi java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

hello i have a problem i have an excel file i have recovered data from this file, then i have created a function to test if the patche exists in another sheet or not everything works well until the ... then I want to display before each patche "Yes" if the patche exists otherwise "no" but the problem is that when creating the output file it displays me all patches "no" even if the patches exist

this is the code :

```
//Create Other rows and cells with data
for (int i = 0; i < patches.size(); i++) {
    if (patches.get(i).getOrigin_Environment().endsWith("MT22")) {
        Row roww = sheet_outputMT22.createRow(i+1);
        roww.createCell(0).setCellValue(patches.get(i).getVaFxNumber());
        roww.createCell(1).setCellValue(patches.get(i).getVaVersion());
        roww.createCell(2).setCellValue(patches.get(i).getVaPackage());
        roww.createCell(3).setCellValue(patches.get(i).getVaLevmat());
        roww.createCell(4).setCellValue(patches.get(i).getOrigin_Environment());
        roww.createCell(5).setCellValue(patches.get(i).getVaSrcCode());
        roww.createCell(6).setCellValue(patches.get(i).getInstalled());
    } else if (patches.get(i).getOrigin_Environment().endsWith("DV46")) {
        Row rowww = sheet_outputDV46.createRow(i+1);
        rowww.createCell(0).setCellValue(patches.get(i).getVaFxNumber());
        rowww.createCell(1).setCellValue(patches.get(i).getVaVersion());
        rowww.createCell(2).setCellValue(patches.get(i).getVaPackage());
        rowww.createCell(3).setCellValue(patches.get(i).getVaLevmat());
        rowww.createCell(4).setCellValue(patches.get(i).getOrigin_Environment());
        rowww.createCell(6).setCellValue(patches.get(i).getVaSrcCode());
    }
}

try {
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("heroes_output.xls");
    workbook_output.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    workbook_output.close();
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Output excel file generated successfuly");

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
}
}

public static void initializeOutputFile() {
    // Create outputWorkbook
    sheet_outputMT22 = workbook_output.createSheet("MT22");
    sheet_outputDV46 = workbook_output.createSheet("DV46");
    // create row
    Row headerRow = sheet_outputMT22.createRow(0);
    Row headerRoww = sheet_outputDV46.createRow(0);
    // Creating cells
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
        Cell cellDv46 = headerRoww.createCell(i);
        cellDv46.setCellValue(columns[i]);
        cell.setCellValue(columns[i]);
    }

    // Resize all columns to fit the content size
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        sheet_outputMT22.autoSizeColumn(i);
        sheet_outputDV46.autoSizeColumn(i);

    }
}
// Create RF80 List
public static List<String> createRF80List(Sheet envARF80_sheet){

    for (int rowNumberr = 2; rowNumberr <= envARF80_sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNumberr++) {
        HSSFRow row1 = (HSSFRow) envARF80_sheet.getRow(rowNumberr);

        HSSFCell cell_NUMOD = row1.getCell(0);
        Cell cell_NUMODI = row1.getCell(0);
        if (cell_NUMODI == null) {
            cell_NUMODI = new StreamingCell(4, row1.getRowNum());
        }

        double number1 = cell_NUMODI.getNumericCellValue();
        String RF80CELL = new Double(number1).toString();
        listRF80.add(RF80CELL) ; 
    }

    return listRF80 ; 
}


//Create Patches List 
public static List<Patch> createPatches(Sheet validation_sheet) {
    String ins;
    for (int rowNumber = 2; rowNumber <= validation_sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNumber++) {
        HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) validation_sheet.getRow(rowNumber);

        HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(3);
        HSSFCell cell2 = row.getCell(4);
        HSSFCell cell3 = row.getCell(12);

        if (cell != null && cell2 != null) {
            // do something with the cell

            if (cell.getStringCellValue().endsWith("Y") && cell2.getStringCellValue().endsWith("MT22")  ) {

                HSSFCell cell_vafxnumber = row.getCell(0);
                HSSFCell cell_VaVersion = row.getCell(1);
                HSSFCell cell_VaPackage = row.getCell(2);
                HSSFCell cell_VaLevmat = row.getCell(3);

                Cell cell_VaSrcCode = row.getCell(12);
                if (cell_VaSrcCode == null) {
                    cell_VaSrcCode = new StreamingCell(12, row.getRowNum());

                }

                Cell cell_Origin_Environment = row.getCell(4);
                if (cell_Origin_Environment == null) {
                    cell_Origin_Environment = new StreamingCell(4, row.getRowNum());
                }

                double number = cell_vafxnumber.getNumericCellValue();
                String number_string = new Double(number).toString();
                String VaVersion = cell_VaVersion.getStringCellValue();
                String VaPackage = cell_VaPackage.getStringCellValue();
                String VaLevmat = cell_VaLevmat.getStringCellValue();
                String Origin_Environment = cell_Origin_Environment.getStringCellValue();
                String VaSrcCode = cell_VaSrcCode.getStringCellValue();
                String installed = verifExistingPatch(listRF80);


                Patch patchh = new Patch(number_string, VaPackage, VaVersion, VaLevmat, Origin_Environment, VaSrcCode , installed);
                patches.add(patchh);
            }
        }

    }
    return patches;
}


public static String verifExistingPatch(List<String> listRF80 ) {

    String exist = ""  ; 

    for(int i = 0 ; i<patches.size() ; i++) {
        for(int j =0 ; j<listRF80.size() ; j++)
            if(patches.get(i).getVaFxNumber().contains(listRF80.get(j)))  {
                exist = "Yes" ;
                System.out.println(patches.get(i).getVaFxNumber() + " Le patche est installes " + exist) ;
            }else if (!patches.get(i).getVaFxNumber().contains(listRF80.get(j))) {
                exist="No";
            }
    }
    return exist;
}
```

Comment: Can you please try with a “return” inside second “for” loop when you find a patch and set return to “Yes”, otherwise you overwrite it with next iterations..

Comment: Can you more  explain to me how? More than. Details

Comment: return exist; // put it on 7th line from the bottom of your code

Comment: same problem man :/

Comment: listRF80 contains getNumericCellValue() not what you checking from patches with get fax number..

Comment: the problem is solved thx i juste change the boucle to while